# for usebackq tokens won't allow me to redirect standard error

Tags: windows, batch-file

**Problem:**

I have a program that writes a string to standard out that I need to capture into an environment variable. If the program encounters any errors it will write them to standard error. I don't want error output to junk up my environment variable, so I want to forward the error messages to `NUL`.

**Here is what worked before error logging:**

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a
in (`modifyFileVersion.exe %userprofile%\version.txt`)
do set FILE_VERISON=%%a
```

**Here is what I want to accomplish:**

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a
in (`modifyFileVersion.exe %userprofile%\version.txt 2>NUL`)  <-- addition of 2>NUL
do set FILE_VERISON=%%a
```

**Here is the error:**

```
2> was unexpected at this time.
```

My understanding is that backqueue tokens allow you to execute a command, instead of pointing to a file or string. I need help correcting my syntax, or a work around to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this - you need to escape some characters in a `for` command tail.

```
2^>nul
```

Comment: This worked, but I also have a problem where `modifyFileVersion.exe` takes an optional parameter. It's taking `2` as the parameter and then redirecting standard output to `NUL`.

Comment: It should not do that if the term is as I suggested.  You could put the term before the `.exe` name though - it should work but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Awesome! It worked like you said originally. I copied and pasted from my script, where I had commented it out... Duh!